# Consume sequence of REST from same client

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

Currently I am consuming REST API which requires sequential call to set authentication.

//Set User

http://localhost:8081/user username

//Get Authentication

http://localhost:8081/password password

The above sequential calls are working perfectly from Browser and Postman. But when I tried to call this from Node JS using axios.get(), server was treating this 2 request as completely different request and throwing an error like "Wrong Auth Sequence".

Is that somehow we need to explicitly mention headers to say that request coming from same client? If yes please help on this.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let api = `${Url}/user name ${username}`;
    console.log('api - ' + api);
    //Set Username
    axios
        .get(api)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            response.data.includes('USER SET') ? setPassword() : console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    res.send('Hello Word');
});

setPassword = () => {
    let api = `${Url}/password ${password}`;
    console.log('api - ' + api);
    axios
        .get(api)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('success: ' + res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('SetPasswordError' + err));
};
```

Comment: As you know http is stateless and you can use cookies for sequential requests

Comment: You really really shouldn't send passwords in urls.

Comment: This was actually a API exposed from 3rd party desktop application. it will only be used within the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The application you are trying to code for is not really a RESTful API and it is expecting you to keep the connection open for multiple requests.